# Filling a web page with an Instagram feed and resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, instagram

I've been searching online for hours now trying to find the best option for pulling in related tagged images from my Instagram feed onto a page that will completely fill the screen. I managed to find [this Instagram plug-in for jQuery](http://potomak.github.com/jquery-instagram/) which I have used at http://www.gezzamondo.co.uk/jennifer.

The thumbnails are really quite small and there are only a few on show... How can I modify this in a way that the squared images will be a lot bigger and will endlessly fill the screen until there are no more images to show?

Comment: Try the InstaMax plugin for embedding Instagram pics. You get 2 options - "max_item_width" and "min_item_width" to adjust the size of your thumbnails and a "Load More" button to satisfy your requirement. Here is the demo - http://demos.codehandling.com/instamax_demo/instamax_live_edit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix to display larger images would be to update line 33 of **jquery.instagram.js**

`.attr('src', photo.images.thumbnail.url)`

to

`.attr('src', photo.images.standard_resolution.url)`

The 20 photo limit is a restriction of the Instagram API, see the [Alternative method section of the jquery-instagram readme](https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram#alternative-method)

Maybe you could look at this as an alternative option? [florinpopa.net/load-instagram-pictures-with-jquery](http://florinpopa.net/load-instagram-pictures-with-jquery/). They seem to have supplied a `count` parameter which allows a larger result of images.

Comment: have u use this alternate option... seems quite good although im not sure how to diplay images from a specific tag and resize these images

Comment: I've not used it in production, only found it whilst looking for a solution to your image size issue. Here's a slightly re-written version which pulls in images that have the tag 'olympics' applied to them, [jsfiddle.net/Damian/4kwzc/](http://jsfiddle.net/Damian/4kwzc/). The images are also resized so they are slightly smaller using css, you probably don't want to take the size down too much as the client will still be using bandwidth to download the full size image!

Comment: hmmm ive just tried adding the code you have written there and nothing seems to be pull through with that olympics tag

Comment: Did you remember to wrap the code with the jQuery ready handler? `$(function() {` code goes here `});` (Jsfiddle adds this code for you if you ask it). - [updated version here](http://jsfiddle.net/Damian/4kwzc/2/)

Comment: sorted it, forgot that i named the div differently